# What programs do designers use to illustrate reports' graphs and maps?

Tags: data-visualisation, chart-design

I am designing monthly and biweekly reports which have many maps and charts.

For the maps, I am using ArcGIS but for the graphs, I am using Excel which I don't think it's suitable and doesn't fit my needs. I can use Illustrator to design my charts but updating and maintaining them is time-consuming

I've looked at several other reports and I am amazed by the consistency of their graphs.

below is two of the examples. Are these using a software to produce these charts or it's completely AI and ID?

Example 1: http://visionofhumanity.org/app/uploads/2017/11/Global-Terrorism-Index-2017.pdf)

Example 2: https://www.humanitarianresponse.info/system/files/documents/files/wos_response_september_2017_171127_0.pdf

Comment: You can make your own charts that update if you wish ist not that hard.

Comment: I use Illustrator... sometimes its chart functions.. sometimes I draw from scratch. Depends upon the chart/graph.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say some of these are custom-made, perhaps based on Excel or similar, but then re-done on top. If you use a program to quickly visualize the information, it should be quite easy to draw something original using the proportions from your original output - especially if you already use Illustrator!

Alternatively, you could create the graphs using an online service, but that means in most cases you will have to start from scratch if there's a change. I haven't tried these myself, but a quick search suggests:

- [Plot.ly](https://plot.ly/create/) (these look pretty sharp!)
- [Raw Graph](http://rawgraphs.io/) (is on GitHub)
- [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) (mostly for diagrams)

Comment: YISELA!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!